# Dojo, basic tab application

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am working on a dojo prototype. I've got several form widgets and tabs working. However how do I start to develop the application properly, to say create a button that toggles the tabs previous/next?

http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/239/

I've tried to include registry - but its not working as expected?

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
   console.log("registry"); //registry.byId('second').set('disabled',!registry.byId('second').get('disabled'));
});
```

Comment: woould likely need to tap into the selectChild function - require(["dijit/registry", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"], function(registry, ContentPane){
    var tabs = registry.byId("myTabContainer");
    var pane = new ContentPane({ title:"Remote Content", href:"remote.html" });
    tabs.addChild(pane);
    tabs.selectChild(pane);
});

Comment: how would I a) get the current tab - and b) select the next tab instead of doing by id -- nextTab = function () {
        var tc = registry.byId("mainTabContainer");
        console.log("next tab", tc);
        var subTab = dijit.byId(1); //tab Id which you want to show
        tc.selectChild(subTab); //Show the selected Tab
    };

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/245/ - how do I select the next tab without placing an id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tc.getIndexOfChild() and tc.selectedChildWidget along with tc.getChildren() to be able to avoid using id's.
Like this:

```
nextTab = function () {
    var tc = registry.byId("mainTabContainer");
    console.log("next tab", tc);
    var currIndex = tc.getIndexOfChild(tc.selectedChildWidget);
    var tabs = tc.getChildren();
    if (currIndex < tabs.length - 1) {
        tc.selectChild(tabs[currIndex+1]);
    }
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/252/